# Where should I direct questions about Wikia?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I've been editing Wikia as an administrator and I would like to know which stackexchange would be most appropriate for some of the programming questions related to my work on Wikia. Like the creation of templates. I know that Wikia has its own forum but they seem to be working to answer my questions as slow as a wet wig so I thought I shouldn't invest my questions all in one basket.

To please my commentators I will give some key examples, I would like to be able to transfer some templates from Wikipedia, like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Infobox_drug) or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Rp).

Comment: Done, I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: There's an Area 51 proposal called "Wikis" which, if it was in beta, would be the perfect home for your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)'s [Help -> Asking](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section:

> Pro Webmasters Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast webmasters focused on how to operate websites

This seems to fit your bill (at least, more so than any other StackExchange site), but if you want to be 100% sure, you could ask if it's ontopic on that [meta site](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks, I shall ask them. If it pans out I will accept your answer!